# Поиск по списку angular js

Tags: angularjs

Ести массив объектов. У каждого объекта есть name,surname и dep.
Отображение:

```
<input ng-model="name">
<p ng-init=" name='' ">Name {{name}}!</p> 
<div class="row" ng-repeat="l in friends | filter:name">
      <div>
          <span class="name_span_name">{{l.name}}</span>
          <span class="name_span_surname">{{l.surname}}</span>
          <span class="name_span_phone">{{l.dep}}</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Вопрос как сделать фильтрацию только по name и surname?

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так, хотя как-то сложно получилось...

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="l in friends | myfilter:name:'name,surname'">


.filter('myfilter', function() {
    return function(input, search, params) {
        search = search.toLowerCase();
        var output = [];
        var keys = params.split(',');
        for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
            for(var j=0; j<keys.length; j++) {
                if(input[i][keys[j]].toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1) {
                    output.push(input[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return output;
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fenex/3pd1n3of/