# Реализовать поиск по списку на Angular 2.x

Tags: html5, angular2, поиск, npm, search

Всем доброго времени суток. Вопрос в общем-то абстрактный, так что кусков кода тут не будет. Только начинаю изучать Angular 2 (с Angular 1 не знаком). Так вот хочу реализовать такую штуку, что после того, как я указал ключевое слово в строке поиска, сразу же выводился список типа ul>li, либо в виле массива объектов - не суть важно.

Должно работать, как тут [Поиск по списку angular js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454381/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83-angular-js)

Понимаю, что я совсем обнаглел, так как есть гугл и можно было бы и там все поискать. Просто не пойму, в какое русло двигаться, не могу найти нормальные примеры.

Так о чем посоветуете почитать, чтобы реализовать подобное?

P.S.: В веб не совсем новичок: хорошо владею html, css и js

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы помогли найти ответ на https://angular.io
Потому что в документации я так и не нашел ничего

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/pipes вот тебе

Comment: Спасбио. Нашел вот еще хорошее решение. Вдруг кому пригодится.
https://long2know.com/2016/11/angular2-filter-pipes/